# Operadores de ponteiros em passagem por referência

Tags: c++, ponteiro, passagem-por-referência

Andei estudando alguns códigos que encontrei na internet, e um deles utilizava uma implementação de protótipo da seguinte forma:

```
void changeMode(Mode &m){
    m.loop = true;
    m.quit = false;
}
```

Veja que a função `changeMode` recebe como parâmetro uma estrutura do tipo `Mode`. O que eu não entendi foi o operador `&`. Ele também passa como argumento da seguinte forma:

```
changeMode(player_mode);
```

Eu gostaria de saber porque foi utilizado o operador `&` e não o operador `*`. O que muda de um para o outro? Até o momento, sei que o `&` representa endereço de memória, e `*` indica um ponteiro. Como poderia uma função estar recebendo um endereço? Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O operador `&`, assim como vários outros em C++, tem mais de uma utilidade, dependendo do contexto onde é aplicado:

- Ele pode ser utilizado para se obter o endereço de uma variável, o caso que você já conhecia.
- Ele faz a operação "e" bit a bit entre dois operandos
- Ele também pode ser utilizado para se declarar parâmetros e variáveis do tipo referência.

Uma referência é semelhante a um ponteiro, uma vez que permite que você altere indiretamente valores em um objeto. As diferenças são:

- Uma vez que a referência é vinculada a um objeto ela não pode passar a apontar para outro
- Você acessa a referência como se fosse uma variável normal, sem necessidade de utilizar o operador `*` para derreferenciar.
- Salvo raros casos, uma referência nunca aponta para `nullptr`

É muito comum se utilizar referências `const` para se passar de parâmetro objetos grandes para funções, quando só se quer observá-los:

```
void teste(const Objeto &obj) { ... }
```

Já quando se quer alterar o parâmetro, escolha entre referências ou ponteiros para parâmetros é praticamente uma questão de estilo. O uso de ponteiros podem deixar mais explícito que a função ira alterar o parâmetro, por exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

Passar por referência (tipo&) é mais "seguro" que por ponteiro (tipo*), pois garante que o objeto nunca será nulo (*).

Por outro lado, se você deseja ter a opção do parâmetro ser nulo, então é obrigado a usar ponteiro.

Passar um objeto como "const tipo&" é mais rápido que passar pelo valor, pois o objeto não precisa ser copiado. (Embora eu acredite que isso já seja otimizado, mas a teoria é esta).

Um objeto passado ou retornado por referência não precisa usar sintaxe diferenciada (com ->) nem dereferenciar ponteiros.

Retonar uma referência a um objeto é uma construção muito poderosa, pois garante que o objeto retornado nunca será nulo.

Para operadores "infix", do tipo +=, -=, *=, etc. a forma correta de implementar é retornar uma referência não-constante ao objeto "esquerdo":

```
tipo& operator+=(tipo& a, const tipo& b); // retorna ref para "a"
```

pois estes operadores implicam que o objeto da esquerda vai ser modificado. Já para operadores binários, o certo é retornar um objeto novo:

```
tipo operator+(const tipo&a, const tipo&b);
```

(*) Sim, eu sei que sempre tem um jeito de passar nulo com casts, mas os objetivos destes recursos do C++ é justamente promover uma programação de nível mais alto, sem casts.